# Run grunt-preprocess before grunt serve

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I need to run [grunt-preprocess](https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-preprocess) before grunt `serve task` is executed in order to have an `index.html` updated with development settings.

It is possible without modify the `index.html` location?

In the dist process I run the grunt-preprocess task just after the `index.html` has been copied in the dest folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the list of tasks that needs to take place when you run `grunt serve` in a similar way to how yeoman does it. Your end result could be something like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('serve', 'start the server and preview your app', [
    'clean:dist',
    'copy',
    'preprocess',
    'connect:livereload',
    'open',
    'watch'
  ]);
```

You are basically registering an `alias` task using `grunt.registerTask`.

> If a task list is specified, the new task will be an alias for one or
>   more other tasks. Whenever this "alias task" is run, every specified
>   tasks in taskList will be run, in the order specified.

In other words, if you are already using a task like [grunt-serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-serve) for instance, you would already have a task named `serve` which you will alias as in the following example:

```
grunt.registerTask('serve', 'start the server and preview your app', [
    'clean:dist',
    'copy',
    'preprocess',
    'serve:dist'
  ]);
```